# SQLite database not supported as external DLR storage in kannel

Tags: kannel

I am using `kannel`.

I have this error

> PANIC: DLR: storage type 'sqlite3' is not supported!

when I run the bearerbox in kannel.

I want to use an external delivery reports storage.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using the latest version? As far as I can see, only 1.4.4 supports sqlite. (If you're using 1.5.0, even though it's a higher number, it was an older development version and didn't support sqlite.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you put all configurations correctly? for sqlite3 you should have following parts in your sqlbox configuration file

```
 group = sqlite3-connection
 id = sqlbox-db
 database = /path/to/kannel.db
 max-connections = 1
```

[This](http://nagendrababuimmadi.blogspot.com/2012/12/steps-to-install-kannel-sms-gateway.html) site has some more details. I hope they will help you. Good Luck.